# How can I get a value from a select and use it as a variable in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a sql proc with two parameters: @id and @id_group.

Consider this table `group_info`

```
ID   ID_Group    SupercededBy   Superceded   status
1    1           null           null         H
2    1           null           null         U
```

Given these parameters:

@id = 2
@id_group = 1

`The first thing` I need to do is to set the row’s `SupercededBy` to `@id`,  where `ID=@id and id_group=@id_group and status='H'`.

Here is the statements I have written:

```
  update group_info
      set supercededby = @id
      where id_group=@id_group and status='H'
```

`The second thing` I need to do is to set the row’s `Superceded` to the `id` whose `SupercededBy` has been just updated from the above statements.

So in this example, `row 2`’s `Superceded` should be updated to `1`.

**But how to write the statements?** I guess the statements might be something like this:

```
update group_info
      set superceded = **old_id**
      where id=@id
```

I know how to get the `old_id`, here it is

```
select id
    from group_info
    where id_group=@id_group and status='H'
```

**But how can I use the values in the above `select` and `insert` the value to the `update` statements  as `old_id`?**

The final table should be

```
ID   ID_Group    SupercededBy   Superceded   status
1    1           2              null         H
2    1           null           1            U
```

I am using MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `SELECT @variable = columnName FROM ...` statement can be used like this:

```
DECLARE @oldId INT

select @oldId  = id
    from group_info
    where id_group=@id_group and status='H'

update group_info
      set superceded = @oldId 
      where id=@id
```

Comment: If the group has more ID, then the latest selected one will be used as @oldId.

Answer (score 0):

with this definition

```
The second thing I need to do is to 
set the row’s Superceded to the id whose SupercededBy has been 
just updated from the above statements.
```

it's a massoperation

```
update group_info
set supercededby = @id
where id_group=@id_group and status='H'


Select ID,supercededby  
into #tmp
from group_info
where id_group=@id_group and status='H'



update group_info
set superceded = #tmp.ID
from #tmp 
where group_info.ID=#tmp.supercededby

Drop table #tmp
```